# Dúvida sobre mod

Tags: python

Sei que o mod é o resto da divisão.

```
12%2 = 0
29%3 = 2
```

Mas alguém poderia me informar qual a razão disso acontecer?

```
12%18 = 12
52%58 = 52
```

Comment: Como o próprio nome diz, isso é o resto da divisão, esses valores acontecem devido ao "denominador" ser maior que o "numerador", pois quanto de resto haveria em 12/18?

Comment: Se vc divide 12 por 18, [o resultado é zero e o resto é 12](https://divisible.info/LongDivision/How-to-calculate-12/divided-by-18-using-long-division.html). O Python só está seguido o que a matemática diz :-)

Answer (score 3):

Vamos pensar na matemática básica:

Se você pegar os resultados 12 e dividi-lo por 18, como você faria?

Bom, acho que todo mundo aqui sabe fazer uma conta de divisão então vamos lá.

```
 12 |18
- 0   0
 12
```

Pronto. Depois desse ponto teremos que usar a vírgula para conseguir continuar a divisão, logo, deixa de ser um número **inteiro**. Com isso chegamos ao resultado que `12 % 18 == 12`.

Answer (score 0):

A função MOD devolve o resto depois de núm ser dividido pelo divisor.

- O cálculo do resto de 12 por 18 = 12
- O cálculo do resto de 52 por 58 = 52